# Updating OpenSSL in OSX

Tags: apache, openssl

I am using 10.9 with Server app 3, and right now i am using an obsolete connection with TLS 1.0, RSA and AES_128CBC with HMAC-SHA1 (that cames by default).

While i was trying to upgrade openssl, i notice that when i tried to upgrade it says that openssl is not installed but it is.

```
remote:~ root# port upgrade openssl
Error: openssl is not installed
remote:~ root# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
```

So i would like to know how can i upgrade it, and why is not being detected as installed?

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015 is the version installed by OS X 10.9(.5) (Mavericks) and resides in /usr/bin/.

MacPorts neither installs nor updates/upgrades genuine Apple (OK, OpenSSL is not Apple but it's part of their basic BSD package) system software. MacPorts' standard realm is /opt/...

You would have to **install** a newer OpenSSL version with MacPorts - if available.

Comment: Thanks for the response klanomath! I have tried to install openssl through mac ports but now i am having an issue with linking to new openssl from macports instead of the old one who came with OS X. It simply doesnt link. I have done dorlandode answer here and nothing (i dont have dotnet in this system so didnt run that last line): https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/597

Comment: @SipriusPT dorlandode's answer (or receipt) is (or works) for the homebrew (also a OS X package manager) installed openssl only. You have to search in a MacPorts forum for a proper answer how to link openssl libs.

Comment: Ah i yes my mistake i said mac ports instead of brew. I will do that. Thanks again!